# Difference between Variance and 2nd moment

Tags: variance

I understand that

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 $

And that the second moment, variance, is

$E(X^2)$

How is variance simultaneously $E(X^2)$ and $E(X^2) - E(X)^2$?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

$$
\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \text{raw moment}\\
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X-\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^n\right] = \text{central moment}
$$
where the 2nd central moments represents the variance.

only equal when $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ as with $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Answer (score 9):

Simple: $$\operatorname{Var}(X)\neq E(X^2)$$

The second moment is not, in general, equal to variance.

Comment: Under which conditions is the second moment equal to variance?

Comment: @slimydummy If $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=E(X^2)$, so use some algebra and you get...

Comment: That was dumb of me. Thank you

Comment: @slimydummy True to your name. :)  But the thruth is that there are no stupid question but maybe stupid answers.