# Why is variance equal to second moment minus squared mean?

Tags: intuition, variance

This possibly should be posted as comment on answer here, but I do not have enough reputation points: [Difference between Variance and 2nd moment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030437/difference-between-variance-and-2nd-moment/2030444)

The formula for calculating variance goes as follows:

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$

I have seen (and done) algebraic development of that formula, but that is just a bunch of symbols with that formula falling out on the right side after the last equal sign. My question is about the intuition behind that (the "3blue1brown-kind-of-explanation" of it)?

I have also done a lot of googling, but the only thing going remotely towards the answer is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNkNf2TuvPg But it is again just a lot of symbols and no intuition. However, understanding the formulas there may lead towards the answer?

Comment: there is a post about this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254357/intuition-geometric-or-other-of-varx-ex2-ex2