# The correct way to integrate the variational free-energy formula

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance, entropy

Lets define the following probability density distributions as:
$$
\begin{align}
p(θ) &= N(θ; 0,1) \\
q(θ) &= N(θ; μ,σ^2)\\
p(y|θ,x) &= N(y; θx,σ_n^2)
\end{align} 
$$
where $N(x; m,v)$ means $x$ is a univariate Gaussian random variable density distribution with mean $m$ and variance $v$.

Calculate variational free-energy
$$
F(q(θ)) = \int dθ\, q(θ) \left[\log q(θ) - \log p(θ) - \log p(y|θ,x)\right]
$$

According to [Difference between Variance and 2nd moment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030437/difference-between-variance-and-2nd-moment), I cannot simplify $\int dθ\, q(θ)(θ - μ)^2$ to $σ^2$, because $μ$ is not $0$?

According to https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/09/01/gaussian-entropy/, this is also the assumption when calculating the entropy:
$$
H(θ) = - ∫ q(θ) \log q(θ) dθ  = 0.5 \log(2πσ^2) + 0.5
$$
meaning I cannot do this either?

If this is the case, how do I calculate the original integral?

Can I simplify $\int dθ\, q(θ)θ^2$?

### Edit1

About @Ricky's comment "how can a random variable follow two distributions", I think the intended meaning of the question is  being an input of a function. The two random variables may be $P$ and $Q$, $P\sim N(0,1)$ and $Q\sim (μ,σ^2)$

### Edit2

About @Joako's comment, I don't think () and $+^2⋅()$ are the same, because:

$$
q(θ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(\theta-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
$$

$$
p(θ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-\theta^2}{2}}\\
$$

@JimB suggested $∫()^2 d=^2+^2$, why?

If I apply the integration by parts formula:
$$
   ∫u \cdot dv = uv - ∫v \cdot du\\
   u = θ^2\\
   dv = q(θ) dθ\\
   du = 2θ dθ\\
   v = ∫q(θ) dθ = 1
   $$

so

$
   ∫θ^2q(θ)dθ\\
   =θ^2-∫2θ dθ\\
   =θ^2-(θ^2+C)\\
   =C
   $

?

Comment: How can $\theta$ simultaneously be $N(0,1)$ and  $N( μ,σ^2)$?

Comment: $\int q(\theta) (\theta-0)^2=\int q(\theta) \theta^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2$

Comment: why $∫()^2=^2+^2$?

Comment: The variance is always the second _central_ moment, if defined, in which case it's the second _raw_ moment iff the mean is $0$.

Comment: Are you aware of the formula?$$\text{Var}(x)=E[x^2]-(E[x])^2$$

Comment: @Joako yes, I have changed my question a bit, please see the edit

Comment: Let me see if I am following your notation: Does the definitions of $p(\theta)$ and $q(\theta)$ implies that $q(\theta)=\mu+\sigma^2\cdot p(\theta)$??... If this is right, How you express the value $p(y|\theta,\ x)$ in terms of $p(y)$?

Comment: @Joako
I don't think it can imply that, see edit 2

Comment: I got confused indeed with the notation since $p(y|\theta,x)$ looks like a conditional probability: Could you explicitely expand what this term means? Then the variable $y$ is going to be a "constant" when integrating respect to $\theta$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
F(q(θ)) &= \int dθ\, q(θ) \left[\log q(θ) - \log p(θ) - \log p(y|θ,x)\right]\\
&= \int dθ\, q(\theta)\left[\log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(\theta-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) - \log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-\theta^2}{2}}\right) - \log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_n^2}} e^{\frac{-(y-\theta x)^2}{2\sigma_n^2}}\right)\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim q(\theta)} \left\{\log \sqrt{\frac{2\pi\sigma_n^2}{\sigma^2}}-\frac{(\theta-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{\theta^2}{2} + \frac{(y-\theta x)^2}{2\sigma_n^2}\right\}\\
&=  \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{2\pi\sigma_n^2}{\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim q(\theta)} \{(\theta-\mu)^2\} + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim q(\theta)} \{\theta^2\} +\frac{1}{2\sigma_n^2} \mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim q(\theta)} \{(y-\theta x)^2\}
\end{align}
Now, can you compute the expectations using the distribution $q(\cdot)$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to compute $\mathbb{E}_{\theta\sim q(\theta)} \{\theta^2\}$

Comment: Please look at the moments of a Gaussian random variable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: To confirm, it is $^2+^2$?

Comment: Yes, thats right!